# Aside-element on simple grid-design sticks, but not all the way to the bottom of the main-element

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, sticky

I have a simple grid-design (see snippet below, make sure to watch it in fullscreen) and want the aside-element to stick as long as the main-element's height is not met through scrolling.

The aside-elements do in fact stick, but only for a portion of the height of the main-element. Any ideas on how to change it to the desired behavior?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

:root {
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  --grid-row-height: 90px;
  --container-gap: 2rem;
  --container-padding: 2rem;
  
  --rem-xxs: 0.5rem;
  --rem-xs: 0.75rem;
  --rem-s: 1rem;
  --rem-m: 1.25rem;
  --rem-xm: 1.5rem;
  --rem-l: 2rem;
  --rem-xl: 2.5rem;
  --rem-xxl: 3rem;
  --rem-4s: calc(4 * var(--rem-s));
  --rem-5s: calc(5 * var(--rem-s));
  --rem-6s: calc(6 * var(--rem-s));
  
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-accent: "Roboto", sans-serif;

  --fs-small: clamp(var(--rem-xs), 0.5vw, var(--rem-s));
  --fs-normal: clamp(var(--rem-s), 1vw, var(--rem-m));
  --fs-big: clamp(var(--rem-m), 1.25vw, var(--rem-xm));
  --fs-xbig: clamp(var(--rem-xm), 1.5vw, var(--rem-l));
  --fs-xxbig: clamp(var(--rem-l), 1.5vw, var(--rem-xl));

  --fw-light: 100;
  --fw-normal: 300;
  --fw-bold: 400;
  --fw-xbold: 500;
  --fw-xxbold: 700;
  
  --clr-primary: #333333;
  --clr-accent: #EA161F;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: var(--clr-primary);
}

body, p, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
  font-size: var(--fs-normal);
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: var(--grid-row-height) auto var(--grid-row-height);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav search"
    "main aside"
    "footer footer";
  margin: var(--container-gap);
  gap: var(--container-gap);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 2 * var(--container-gap));
}

  #grid > * {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
  }

  nav { grid-area: nav; }
  #search { grid-area: search; }
  main { grid-area: main; }
  aside { grid-area: aside; }
  footer { grid-area: footer; }

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

  nav > * {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: var(--container-gap);
  }

  #logo img {
    height: calc(var(--grid-row-height) / 100 * 50);
  }

  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: var(--container-padding);
  }

    nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
      font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
      height: var(--grid-row-height);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: var(--clr-primary);
    }

    nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
      color: var(--clr-accent);
    }

#search {
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: var(--container-padding);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: var(--container-padding);
}

  #search form {
    width: 100%;
  }

  input[type=search] {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--grid-row-height);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    outline: none;
  }

  #search a {
    color: var(--clr-accent);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: var(--fw-xbold);
  }

main {
  
}

aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: var(--container-gap);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: var(--container-gap);
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

  aside > * {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
  }

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--clr-accent) !important;
  color: white;
}

  footer > * {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: var(--container-gap);
  }

  footer a {
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dee405e1bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid">
        <nav>
          <div>
            <div id="logo">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://berufsbildungscenter.ch/app/uploads/Logo_KAIO.png"></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-masks-theater fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="search">
          <form>
            <input type="search" value="" placeholder="SEARCH">
          </form>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
        </div>
      <main>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
      </main>
      <aside>
        <div>
          ASIDE DIV
        </div>
        
        <div>
          ASIDE DIV
        </div>
      </aside>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <span><i class="far fa-copyright"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;2016&dash;2023 by learni.ch - Ein Produkt der           <a href="https://duolopment.ch" target="_blank">duolopment KLG</a></span>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">AGB</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Version: Aphrodite (2.7)</li>
              <li><a href="#">Releasenotes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your much appreciated help.

Comment: Could you put a runnable snippet into your answer?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I don't know how to do that... Therefore I posted an URL to a codepen (which is runnable there).

Comment: Please read the link I gave, then you will know how to do it. The reason for this is, partly, so that if that link goes down (or gets mended) future readers can still benefit from your question.

Comment: I've added a runnable snippet to the post as requested (thanks for the how-to-article). So does anybody know, what's going on here?

Comment: Thanks for showing the code. Please could you first of all correct the HTML (and any related CSS) as currently you have used a head element within the body. I think you meant header.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position?v=example for an explanation of what the element is sticking to.

Comment: Your search element has disappeared.

Comment: I removed the header-element entirely since it is in fact not needed... Now, the search element is visible again but the initial problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `<aside>` has a large height which prevents it from scrolling all the way down to the bottom. By adjusting its height you can achieve the desired effect. I set its height to `height: max-content` and it seems to be working as intended.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

:root {
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  
  --grid-row-height: 90px;
  --container-gap: 2rem;
  --container-padding: 2rem;
  
  --rem-xxs: 0.5rem;
  --rem-xs: 0.75rem;
  --rem-s: 1rem;
  --rem-m: 1.25rem;
  --rem-xm: 1.5rem;
  --rem-l: 2rem;
  --rem-xl: 2.5rem;
  --rem-xxl: 3rem;
  --rem-4s: calc(4 * var(--rem-s));
  --rem-5s: calc(5 * var(--rem-s));
  --rem-6s: calc(6 * var(--rem-s));
  
  --ff-primary: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --ff-accent: "Roboto", sans-serif;

  --fs-small: clamp(var(--rem-xs), 0.5vw, var(--rem-s));
  --fs-normal: clamp(var(--rem-s), 1vw, var(--rem-m));
  --fs-big: clamp(var(--rem-m), 1.25vw, var(--rem-xm));
  --fs-xbig: clamp(var(--rem-xm), 1.5vw, var(--rem-l));
  --fs-xxbig: clamp(var(--rem-l), 1.5vw, var(--rem-xl));

  --fw-light: 100;
  --fw-normal: 300;
  --fw-bold: 400;
  --fw-xbold: 500;
  --fw-xxbold: 700;
  
  --clr-primary: #333333;
  --clr-accent: #EA161F;
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; }
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: var(--clr-primary);
}

body, p, input, select, textarea {
  font-family: var(--ff-primary);
  font-weight: var(--fw-normal);
  font-size: var(--fs-normal);
  line-height: 1.5;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: var(--grid-row-height) auto var(--grid-row-height);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav search"
    "main aside"
    "footer footer";
  margin: var(--container-gap);
  gap: var(--container-gap);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 2 * var(--container-gap));
}

  #grid > * {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
  }

  nav { grid-area: nav; }
  #search { grid-area: search; }
  main { grid-area: main; }
  aside { grid-area: aside; }
  footer { grid-area: footer; }

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

  nav > * {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: var(--container-gap);
  }

  #logo img {
    height: calc(var(--grid-row-height) / 100 * 50);
  }

  nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    gap: var(--container-padding);
  }

    nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
      font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
      height: var(--grid-row-height);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: var(--clr-primary);
    }

    nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
      color: var(--clr-accent);
    }

#search {
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: var(--container-padding);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: var(--container-padding);
}

  #search form {
    width: 100%;
  }

  input[type=search] {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--grid-row-height);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    outline: none;
  }

  #search a {
    color: var(--clr-accent);
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: var(--fw-xbold);
  }

main {
  
}

aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: var(--container-gap);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: var(--container-gap);
  background-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: max-content;
}

  aside > * {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
    padding: var(--container-padding);
  }

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: var(--clr-accent) !important;
  color: white;
}

  footer > * {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    gap: var(--container-gap);
  }

  footer a {
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: var(--fw-bold);
  }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dee405e1bd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grid">
        <nav>
          <div>
            <div id="logo">
              <a href="#"><img src="https://berufsbildungscenter.ch/app/uploads/Logo_KAIO.png"></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-masks-theater fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sliders fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <div id="search">
          <form>
            <input type="search" value="" placeholder="SEARCH">
          </form>
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass"></i></a>
        </div>
      <main>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
        MAIN<br>
      </main>
      <aside>
        <div>
          ASIDE DIV
        </div>
        
        <div>
          ASIDE DIV
        </div>
      </aside>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <span><i class="far fa-copyright"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;2016&dash;2023 by learni.ch - Ein Produkt der           <a href="https://duolopment.ch" target="_blank">duolopment KLG</a></span>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">AGB</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fas fa-code"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Version: Aphrodite (2.7)</li>
              <li><a href="#">Releasenotes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! The max-content was exactly what I was looking for. :-)